# about to install linux, full format or partition?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I'm about to switch from windows to ubuntu but I'm pondering if I should do a whole format when installing ubuntu or keep windows on the side.
I'm saving some files that I care about on an external hard drive but I'm anxious I might miss some of those. I don't save everything because it's too large (and larger than my hdd).

My question is whether I should do a full format or install ubuntu in another partition :

- Since I might miss some files and I'm planning to install ubuntu and let the windows install intact (until I'm sure there is no file I forgot to save).
  I'm planning to remove the windows files in the upcoming months. I'm wondering if making an install "next to" windows is not as clean as doing a full formatting ? In other words, ubuntu will be installed in another partition (I guess) then the windows partition will be deleted, will ubuntu then take the whole hard drive for itself ? Will there be any residual garbage from windows ?

If it's indeed cleaner to remove everything and install ubuntu I'll take the risk of missing some files.

Comment: Since, its your first time you might get frustrated so its recommended to dual boot, in case you change your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers:

1. If you use a dual boot you can keep track of how many times you still use  Windows.
2. If you keep files on an NTFS formatted place you probably want to keep a workable version of Windows. When partitions have errors on NTFS it mosttimes is better to use Windows to fix it. Easy way out: when you have Ubuntu you can take the files out of there, format to EXT and move them back.
3. If you have the space to spare you can shrink Windows to a bare minimum it will boot with and set Grub to boot straight into Ubuntu. You never going to see the option to boot Windows but it is still there.

Mind though: it is also possible to use Ubuntu and install Windows inside of Ubuntu (with VM-Ware, Virtual Box).

> I'm wondering if making an install "next to" windows is not as clean as doing a full formatting ?

You can always remove Windows from inside Ubuntu and re-install grub so it ends up at the beginning of your disk.

> In other words, ubuntu will be installed in another partition (I guess) then the windows partition will be deleted, will ubuntu then take the whole hard drive for itself ?

That depends on what you choose during install. If you have Windows + unallocated space you can create a dual boot by installing Ubuntu into the unallocated space. If you do not have unallocated space you can only remove Windows. That will remove -ALL- partitions (so in Windows terms: it will also delete D:, E:).

Comment: My windows is corrupted and I can't boot on it. It's actually just about the files (musics I did, eclipse projects, mysql server running on localhost) that I don't want to lose. After reading your comment I feel like the easiest solution for someone not at all familiar with all this is just a clean install and save what I can on my external HDD. I've only 138 go free space on my HDD and about 500 go in windows (granted I don't need to save everything, but that's what I was anxious about).

Comment: Yes sir I would agree on that. If you are unsure you can also use our Live session (before the installation) to save your files on the c: and/or d: drive.   The Live session will actually show you all partitions in the launcher (including the Windows partitions). That might be your best way to go.

Comment: That's what I was currently doing actually (i'm writing this while on ubuntu live). Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to keep Windows, do a dual-boot. If you do not want Windows anymore I would recommend you to format the full disk to make the Ubuntu Installation. If you keep Windows, Install Ubuntu and THEN remove Windows, Ubuntu will not take up the whole disk, and you have to consider that a system in the first partition of a disk is always faster.